# Typescript: How to specify return type for Array.filter() method

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm quite a new in TypeScript and after JavaScript it's exiting but sometimes hard to work with.

I have a method:

```
// Part of Vuex store code
state = ...

readOneAsr: (asrId: number): IAsr | undefined => {
   const filteredInstances = state.items.filter((asr) => asr.id === asrId)
   if (filteredInstances.length > 0) {
      return { ...filteredInstances[0] }
   }
}

// Method from Vue component
...
get relatedAsr(): IAsr[] {
   if (!this.instance) {
      return []
   }

   return this.asr_ids
      .map((aid) => readOneAsr(aid))
      .filter((asr) => asr !== undefined)
}
```

Method `readOneAsr` can return `undefined` but at the end the method `relatedAsr` returns only `IAsr` instances.

So I specified `relatedAsr(): IAsr[]`. But eslint shows me an error:

```
 83:5 Type '(IAsr | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'IAsr[]'.
      Type 'IAsr | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IAsr'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IAsr'.
```

How to fix this error? Easiest way is just specify return type to `(IAsr | undefined)[]` but I don't like this solution..

Comment: Could you please share minimum reproducable code?

Comment: Make the return type of the filter callback a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).